# FLEX/BISON generate location.hh, position.hh, stack.hh in different folder

Tags: c++, cmake, bison, flex-lexer

I have folder structure like this

```
include/
src/
 | parser.yy
 | scanner.ll
```

and in the `src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(BisonOutput ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/_parser.cpp)

IF(BISON_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
      OUTPUT ${BisonOutput}
      COMMAND ${BISON_EXECUTABLE}
              --defines=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/_parser.hpp
              --output=${BisonOutput}
              ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/parser.yy
      COMMENT "Generating parser"
    )
ENDIF()

SET(FlexOutput ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/_scanner.cpp)

IF(FLEX_FOUND)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
      OUTPUT ${FlexOutput}
      COMMAND ${FLEX_EXECUTABLE}
              --outfile=${FlexOutput}
              ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/scanner.ll
      COMMENT "Generating scanner"
    )
ENDIF()
```

However the files locations.hh, position.hh and stack.hh are generated inside the `src` directory. Is it possible to somehow specify that i want these files generated inside the `include` directory?

I am using Bison 3.0.4 and Flex 2.6.4

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Bison/Flex allows you to generate them in a separate location, but you can use CMake to copy them to the `include` directory once they are generated. Add another `add_custom_command` call with [`PRE_BUILD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) to ensure they are copied *before* building your target:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    TARGET MyTarget PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/locations.hh ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/position.hh ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/stack.hh ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work because (I think) flex/bison will hardcode the includes in the generated .cpp files and somehow expects them to be in the same dir. I might be wrong but I haven't got it work this way.